# Как сделать проверку на нечетность в питон без условных операторов?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
s = bool(a % 2 == 0 or b % 2 == 0)
print(s)
```

Этот код проверяет на четность, но требуется проверка на нечетность.

Comment: инвертируйте результат и будет проверка на нечетность

Answer (score 2):

Используйте побитовые операции

```
s = bool((a | b) & 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

можно через функцию any():

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
s = any([a%2, b%2, c%2])  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
s = bool(a % 2 == 1 or b % 2 == 1)
print(s)
```

Ну по сути, изменив 0 на 1 мы проверяем нечетность